# my stylsheet from php file not working

Tags: php

I have this php file that I want it to act like stylesheet

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");

a:hover
{
color: #00B2ED;
}
.sub-main-menu nav ul  li a
{
color: #00B2ED;
}
.btn-fc
{
  background: #00B2ED none repeat scroll 0 0;
color: #ffffff;
display: inline;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 30px;
margin: 0;
padding: 7px 10px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
z-index: 1;

  border: 0; /* remove border   */
  cursor: pointer;

}

?>
```

And this is how I am calling it like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="user-style.php" />
```

But content does not load. Not any style is working. Is there anything missing?

Comment: Why did you need .css file as .php ??

Comment: Batsy, I will be storing user preferred color scheme that is why it is named as user-style

Comment: You cannot wrap CSS inside <?php ?>. The header() is not necessary. .sub-main-menu nav ul  li a { color: <?php echo $currentColor ?> } instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you the content is not a valid PHP code.

Here is one option to change it:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
// the php parser expect to have php code here, but a:hover is not a php code.
// what we can do is just close the php block, and from here its a regular text file
?>
a:hover
{
color: #00B2ED;
}
.sub-main-menu nav ul  li a
{
color: #00B2ED;
}
.btn-fc
{
  background: #00B2ED none repeat scroll 0 0;
color: #ffffff;
display: inline;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: 500;
line-height: 30px;
margin: 0;
padding: 7px 10px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
z-index: 1;

  border: 0; /* remove border   */
  cursor: pointer;

}
```

> Also - note the explanation inside (in the comments).

Comment: Ah! Thanks for pointing it out! My laziness but thank you anyway :)